# Follow labels in HTML using scrapy

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to understand how scrapy works when I want to extract something from a web page

So I am using the this page to practice https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios?segmento=s-personas

Now I want to get this URLs:

- https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=shopping
- https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=sabores
- https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=decoracion
- https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=salud-y-belleza
- https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=panoramas
- https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=otros

This would be where they are in the HTML code:

```
  <!-- ==================================== HEADER BENEFICIOS ======================================================== -->
  <div class="transition navFixed">

    <div id="webviewHeaderBeneficios" class="headerBeneficios">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="position: relative;">

          <a href="" class="nextMenu hidden-md hidden-lg" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 beneficiosNav">
            <a href="" class="overlayHeader" ng-show="search.length > 0" ng-click="search = null" target="_self"></a>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
              <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios" class="icon-home transition ev-pers-home" target="_self"><span><svg width="41" height="36" viewBox="0 0 41 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>41x36</title><g fill="" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M31.46 12.3V6.9c0-1-.8-1.8-1.78-1.8s-1.77.8-1.77 1.8v1.86l-3.5-3.5c-1.72-1.72-4.72-1.72-6.45 0L6.2 17.02c-.68.7-.68 1.83 0 2.52.7.7 1.83.7 2.52 0L20.46 7.78c.4-.38 1.06-.38 1.44 0l11.74 11.74c.35.35.8.52 1.26.52.45 0 .9-.17 1.26-.52.7-.7.7-1.82 0-2.5l-4.7-4.7z"/><path d="M20.4 11.12L10.1 21.45c-.16.16-.25.38-.25.6v7.54c0 1.76 1.43 3.2 3.2 3.2h5.1v-7.93h5.78v7.92h5.13c1.76 0 3.2-1.44 3.2-3.2v-7.54c0-.23-.1-.45-.26-.6L21.64 11.1c-.34-.34-.9-.34-1.23 0z"/></g></svg><br><p>Inicio</p></span></a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=shopping" class="icon-shopping transition ev-pers-shopping" target="_self"><span><svg width="41" height="36" viewBox="0 0 41 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>41x36</title><g fill="" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M26 12.76v-3.5C26 5.82 23.4 3 20.2 3c-3.2 0-5.82 2.8-5.82 6.27v3.5c0 .42.32.77.72.77.4 0 .73-.35.73-.78v-3.5c0-2.6 1.96-4.7 4.36-4.7 2.4 0 4.36 2.1 4.36 4.7v3.5c0 .43.32.78.72.78.4 0 .72-.35.72-.78"/><path d="M29.83 10.88c-.04-1-.83-1.16-.83-1.16h-1.62v2.1l-.02 1.02c0 1.18-.95 2.13-2.13 2.13s-2.13-.95-2.13-2.13c0-.37.08-1.02.08-1.02v-2.1h-5.95l-.03 2.1s.04.65.04 1.02c0 1.18-.95 2.13-2.13 2.13-1.16 0-2.12-.95-2.12-2.13 0-.37.03-1.02.03-1.02v-2.1h-1.26s-.98 0-1.17.98C10.4 11.57 9 29.7 9 30.2c0 1.8 1.94 1.92 1.94 1.92s17.77.12 18.45 0c.66-.12 1.9-.98 1.8-2.52-.4-5.46-1.34-17.94-1.37-18.72z"/></g></svg><br><p>Shopping</p></span></a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=sabores" class="icon-sabores transition ev-pers-sabores" target="_self"><span><svg width="41" height="36" viewBox="0 0 41 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>41x36</title><g fill="" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M34.97 5.65c0-1-.34-1.82-1-2.47-.22-.22-.57-.24-.82-.05-.1.1-2.14 2.1-25.95 25.73-.7.7-.7 1.87 0 2.57.35.35.8.54 1.3.54s.95-.2 1.3-.53l7.76-7.7c3-2.98 4.3-3.4 5-3.44 1.35-.1 2.5-.6 3.36-1.44 3.9-3.86 9.06-9.42 9.05-13.2zM10.97 13.86c.84.82 1.98 1.3 3.3 1.4.72.05 1.6.5 2.74 1.4.13.08.26.12.4.12.15 0 .3-.06.43-.18l1.95-1.93c.2-.22.23-.56.04-.8-1.27-1.6-1.42-2.43-1.4-2.9 0-1.08-.45-2.15-1.3-2.98l-.15-.15-5.5-4.6c-.26-.23-.64-.2-.86.06-.2.26-.17.64.08.86l5 4.2-1.7 1.66L8.94 5c-.24-.24-.62-.24-.86 0-.24.23-.24.62 0 .85l5.06 5.02-1.7 1.7L7.1 8.03c-.22-.24-.6-.25-.85-.02-.25.24-.26.62-.03.87l4.74 4.98zM34.83 28.96l-8.4-8.32c-.2-.2-.5-.24-.75-.1-.67.42-1.45.7-2.3.85-.23.03-.42.2-.48.4-.07.22-.02.46.15.62l9.18 9.1c.35.35.8.54 1.3.54s.95-.2 1.3-.53c.34-.34.53-.8.53-1.28 0-.5-.2-.94-.53-1.3z"/></g></svg><br><p>Sabores</p></span></a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=decoracion" class="icon-deco transition ev-pers-decoracion" target="_self"><span><svg width="41" height="36" viewBox="0 0 41 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>41x36</title><path d="M9.05 19.38l3.78-15.1c.2-.74.86-1.28 1.6-1.28h11.2c.77 0 1.42.52 1.6 1.27l3.8 15.1c.25 1.07-.55 2.08-1.63 2.08h-8.2V26c0 2.23 1.58 4.1 3.67 4.52.56.1.95.62.95 1.2 0 .65-.54 1.2-1.2 1.2h-9.07c-.67 0-1.2-.55-1.2-1.2 0-.58.38-1.07.94-1.2 2.08-.43 3.63-2.3 3.63-4.5v-4.57h-8.2c-1.14 0-1.94-1-1.68-2.07" fill="" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg><br><p>Decoración</p></span></a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=salud-y-belleza" class="icon-salud transition ev-pers-salud-y-belleza" target="_self"><span><svg width="41" height="36" viewBox="0 0 41 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>41x36</title><g fill="" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M18.3 10.9V7.8h-6.97v3.1c-1.92.33-3.35 1.07-4.22 2.22-.9 1.17-1.2 2.72-.95 4.62 1.7 12.44 3 13.92 3.4 14.4 1.07 1.23 3.33 1.42 4.62 1.42h1.3c1.28 0 3.55-.2 4.6-1.42.43-.48 1.7-1.96 3.4-14.4.27-1.9-.05-3.45-.94-4.62-.88-1.15-2.3-1.9-4.22-2.22zm3.48 6.6c-1.48 10.76-2.6 13.03-3 13.5-.43.5-1.73.82-3.32.82h-1.3c-1.57 0-2.87-.32-3.3-.82-.4-.47-1.52-2.74-3-13.5-.2-1.42 0-2.54.6-3.32.6-.78 1.67-1.3 3.16-1.57.83-.14 1.43-.86 1.43-1.7V9.55h3.53v1.35c0 .84.6 1.56 1.43 1.7 1.5.27 2.56.8 3.17 1.58.6.78.8 1.9.6 3.32z"/><path d="M15.15 14.04h-.66c-1.74 0-5.5.24-4.97 4.7.6 4.9 1.35 9.56 2.15 10.6.6.8 2.04.9 2.75.9h.77c.72 0 2.16-.1 2.75-.9.8-1.04 1.57-5.7 2.16-10.6.55-4.46-3.22-4.7-4.95-4.7zM33.1 16.3h-1.2V8.44c.73-3.93.8-3.95.8-4.46 0-.54-.42-.97-.95-.97-.23 0-.44.1-.6.23-.17-.14-.4-.23-.62-.23-.23 0-.44.1-.6.23-.18-.14-.4-.23-.62-.23-.52 0-.95.43-.95.97 0 .5.08.53.8 4.45v7.9h-1.18c-.63 0-1.14.5-1.14 1.14V32.4c0 .65.5 1.16 1.14 1.16h5.12c.62 0 1.13-.5 1.13-1.15V17.47c0-.63-.5-1.15-1.14-1.15z"/></g></svg><br><p>Salud y Belleza</p></span></a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=panoramas" class="icon-panoramas transition ev-pers-panoramas" target="_self"><span><svg width="41" height="36" viewBox="0 0 41 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>41x36</title><path d="M38.2 14.54L36.53 12l-.24.17c-1.42.87-3.32.44-4.23-.96-.9-1.4-.5-3.23.93-4.1l.26-.14-1.65-2.53c-.47-.73-1.46-.95-2.2-.5l-6.96 4.25c.57.13 1 .62 1 1.23 0 .7-.6 1.26-1.3 1.25-.7 0-1.24-.58-1.24-1.28 0-.1.04-.2.07-.3l-17.5 10.7c-.76.47-.98 1.43-.5 2.16l1.66 2.55c.1-.1.23-.18.35-.26 1.43-.87 3.32-.44 4.23.96.92 1.4.5 3.24-.92 4.1-.12.08-.26.15-.4.2l1.67 2.55c.48.73 1.47.96 2.2.5L29.33 21.8c-.4-.2-.7-.63-.7-1.13 0-.7.6-1.26 1.3-1.25.68 0 1.23.57 1.23 1.27l6.55-4.02c.75-.45.97-1.4.5-2.14m-12.84-2.3c0 .7-.58 1.25-1.28 1.24-.7 0-1.25-.6-1.25-1.28 0-.7.6-1.26 1.3-1.25.68 0 1.24.58 1.23 1.28m1.93 2.82c0 .7-.6 1.26-1.3 1.25-.7 0-1.25-.58-1.24-1.28 0-.7.6-1.26 1.3-1.25.68 0 1.24.58 1.23 1.28m1.92 2.83c0 .7-.58 1.25-1.28 1.25-.7 0-1.26-.6-1.25-1.3 0-.68.58-1.24 1.28-1.23.7 0 1.25.58 1.24 1.28" fill="" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg><br><p>Panoramas</p></span></a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=otros" class="icon-otros transition ev-pers-otros" target="_self"><span><svg width="41" height="36" viewBox="0 0 41 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>41x36</title><path d="M33.48 10.4c-.2-.33-.63-.44-1-.26l-1.45.78c-.36.18-.48.57-.28.9.12.2.4.3.63.3.12 0 .24-.03.36-.06l1.46-.8c.36-.16.48-.55.28-.87zm-6.9 10.7c.97-1.33 1.85-3 1.85-5.1 0-2.1-.94-4-2.42-5.4-1.47-1.4-3.5-2.25-5.6-2.25h-.2c-2.12 0-4.14.86-5.62 2.25-1.48 1.4-2.42 3.3-2.42 5.4 0 2.1.88 3.77 1.85 5.1.97 1.38 2 2.27 2.32 3.25.2.76.22 1.34.3 1.65.1.3 0 .25.4.42.34.12 1.85.23 3.27.22 1.42 0 2.93-.1 3.28-.22.38-.17.3-.13.4-.42.07-.3.07-.9.3-1.65.3-.98 1.34-1.87 2.3-3.24zm1.6-14.84c.2-.32.1-.7-.26-.9-.36-.17-.8-.06-1 .26l-.86 1.32c-.2.32-.08.7.28.88.1.04.23.08.35.08.23 0 .5-.1.62-.32l.87-1.32zM21 5.73V4.2c0-.35-.3-.64-.7-.64-.4 0-.72.3-.72.64v1.53c-.04.35.28.64.7.64.4 0 .72-.28.72-.64zm-6.47 1.2l-.87-1.3c-.2-.33-.63-.44-1-.26-.34.18-.46.57-.26.9l.87 1.3c.1.22.4.33.63.33.12 0 .24-.04.35-.07.36-.18.48-.57.28-.9zm-4.7 4.88c.2-.3.08-.7-.27-.88l-1.47-.78c-.36-.18-.8-.07-1 .25-.2.3-.07.7.28.88l1.47.78c.1.07.23.07.35.07.24 0 .5-.1.63-.32zm6.8 16.83c0 .37.32.67.7.67h5.94c.37 0 .67-.3.67-.67 0-.37-.3-.67-.67-.67h-5.95c-.37 0-.68.3-.68.67zm0 2.82c0 .38.32.67.7.67h2.15c.13 0 .22.06.25.1.14.13.44.23.8.23.32 0 .6-.1.75-.22.04-.03.13-.1.28-.1h1.7c.38 0 .68-.3.68-.68 0-.37-.3-.67-.67-.67h-5.95c-.37 0-.68.3-.68.67z" fill="" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg><br><p>Otros</p></span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 inputSearch" ng-class="mapClass" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="searchIcon" ng-hide="search.length > 0">
              <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="searchIcon" ng-show="search.length > 0">
              <a href="" ng-click="search = null" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <input class="ev-pers-search" type="text" ng-model="search" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 450 }" ng-change="searchChanged(search);" placeholder="Buscar restaurantes, cafés..." maxlength="35">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The URLs I want are under the label `a`, under `li`, under `ul`, and so on

As I understood, If I run `response.css("ul li a::attr(href)")` I should get the URLs under these labels, but what I get it´s a big list of URLs, and it doesn´t have the URLs I want

So what I am trying to understand it´s what I am actually getting when I use `response.css("ul li a::attr(href)")`, what is scrapy understanding?, and what would be the proper way to get what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you got all those other links is because the footer has the same structure (links inside lists), so your initial selector will find those too.

You need to use a more specific selector. Note that the links you want are inside a `div` with the class `beneficiosNav`. This will get you all the links in that section:

```
response.css(".beneficiosNav ul li a::attr(href)")
```

---

Edit: Here is the output I get when opening it with scrapy shell:

`scrapy shell "https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios?segmento=s-personas"`

```
>>> response.css(".beneficiosNav ul li a::attr(href)").getall()
```

And the result of that:

```
['https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios', 
'https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=shopping',
'https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=sabores',
'https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=decoracion',
'https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=salud-y-belleza',
'https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=panoramas',
'https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=otros']
```

Comment: Using that I get:

[![result][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKCEK.png

Why I can´t see the URLs?

Comment: @Jose That looks like an ipython shell. How are you loading the response? Are you sure you're retrieving the correct URL? Which version of Scrapy are you using?

Comment: Yes I was in the rigth URL, that was in teh scrapy shell, I closed it and open a new one and it´s working fine, now I get the same result has you. Thank´s a lot